# Trying to edit/delete records on sql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table in which I need to edit/delete rows off a sql db using php. The problem (tale as old as time) is that neither delete/edit functions work correctly. I get no error messages, so I've been spending hours combing through the code and googling and searching through other similar questions on here and nothing that really addresses my specific problem.

I'm probably missing a quotation mark or something stupid like that, but some pointers would be really appreciated.

here is my editing code:

```
//if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record 
if (isset($_GET['GroomingID']))
{
    //if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
            //make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
            if (is_numeric($_POST['GroomingID']))
                {
                    //get variables from the URL/form
                    $GroomingID = $_POST['GroomingID'];
                    $firstName = htmlentities($_POST['FirstName'], ENT_QUOTES);
                    $lastName = htmlentities($_POST['LastName'], ENT_QUOTES);

                //check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
                    if ($firstName == '' || $lastName == '')
                        {
                    //if they are empty, show an error message and display the form

                            $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields';
                            renderForm($firstName, $lastName, $error, $GroomingID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            //if everything is fine, update the record
                if($stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE grooming SET FirstName = ?, LastName = ? WHERE GroomingID=?"))
            {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $firstName, $lastName, $GroomingID);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
            }
            //show an error message if the query encounters an error
            else
            {
                echo "Error: could not preapre sql statement.";
            }

            //redirect the user once the form is updated
            header("Location: PS_Manage_Appnts.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
    //if the 'id' variable isn't valid, show error message
    else
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
    //if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
    else
    {
        //make sure the 'id' value is valid
        if (is_numeric($_GET['GroomingID']) && $_GET['GroomingID'] > 0)
        {
            //get 'id' from URL
            $id = $_GET['GroomingID'];

            //get the record from the database
            if($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM grooming WHERE GroomingID=?"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("i", $GroomingID);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $stmt->bind_result($GroomingID, $firstName, $lastName);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                //show the form
                renderForm($firstName, $lastName, NULL, $GroomingID);

                $stmt->close();
            }

            //show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement.";
            }
        }
//if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the PS_Manage_Appnts.php page
        else {
                header("location:PS_Manage_Appnts.php");
                exit();
             }
        }
}
```

My delete code (separate from editing code):

```
<?php
//connect to the database
include ("newDBconn.php");

//confirm that the 'id'(in this case, 'GroomingID') variable has been set 
    if (isset($_GET['GroomingID']) && is_numeric($_GET['GroomingID']))
    {
    //get the 'id' variable from the URL
    $GroomingID = $_GET['GroomingID'];

    //delete record from the database
    if ($stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM grooming WHERE GroomingID = '?' LIMIT 1"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $GroomingID);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR: could not prepare sql statement.";
        }
        $link->close();
        // redirect user after delete is successful
        header ("location:PS_Manage_Appnts.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    //if the 'id' variable isn't set, redirect the user
    {
        header("location:PS_Manage_Appnts.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
```

And lastly, the code for my db connection in a separate php file:

```
<?php
//connect to db
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pwdpwd', 'pet_shop');

//check connection
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
```

Notes: I'm aware of msql injection, but a) this is a test on my machine and b) I'd like to fix this problem first. Thank you for the help!

EDIT: I did run this through FireFox's Firebug and got no errors there either. I did, however, notice that when the 'delete' link on my table is clicked, firebug shows this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HlIk.png

There is no code linking the above underlined css file to my delete file (PS_delete_post.php) so I have no idea why it's trying to grab the css file. PS_delete_post.php isn't supposed to have any css linked to it to begin with.

EDIT2: I've changed the $firstName/$lastName variables to all lowercase as per Neo's suggestion. Now when 'edit' is clicked, the user is (correctly) directed to an empty form to input values, but hitting submit **adds** a new row instead of **editing** an existing row. 'Delete' still does not work.

Comment: You see absolutely no errors when you run the code? even no error messages you have output?

Comment: "neither delete/edit functions work correctly".  What does this mean?

Comment: Is your error reporting enabled? Maybe it's disabled and it does not show the error

Comment: You mentioned SQL injection, but prepared statements (which you are using) take care of that.  As to your problem, I'd try to figure out where the script is stopping.  Put in a bunch of echos if you have to.

Comment: @Neo Nope. When I hit edit on a row of the table, I get directed to a form to update my values (which is supposed to happen). There, I can input new values, hit submit, but all that happens is that I get redirected back to the table. Nothing happens when I hit 'delete'.

Comment: sometimes sql column names can act funny when they have mixedcase, try using lower case, maybe?

Comment: @Kai Ah, I wasn't sure if I was (noob of course). I'll try putting in some echos, suggestions where would be helpful!

Comment: @ChrisWillard Sorry for the obtuse language; I meant that when I try hitting delete/edit on a table row, the edit doesn't implement the change its supposed to (see comment to Neo above) and delete doesn't function at all. tl;dr: none of the changes I'm trying to implement to my db through this table are working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending `GroomingID` from Post and Get?

In the Update File you retrieve the ID with this `$GroomingID = $_POST['GroomingID'];` But I am not sure if you sent it from Post or only Get.

Comment: Do you mean you're not sure if I sent it from this? -> 
`if (isset($_GET['GroomingID']))` Or...?

Comment: I'm retrieving the `GroomingID` with GET and sending it with POST, I think.